# SQL Server : grouping by 2 variables, keeping all distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server

I made several attempts at googling a solution to this but I'm finding a hard time generating keywords for an accurate search.

Say I have a table with the following information.

```
A, B  
1, 1  
1, 2  
2, 1
```

If I perform a group by operation on both columns A, B, I'll get a table indexed by the same set, but I'm interested in something of the form:

```
A, B, nRecords  
1, 1, 1  
1, 2, 1  
2, 1, 1  
2, 2, 0
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
   A, B, COUNT(*) nRecords 
FROM 
   table 
GROUP BY 
   A, B
```

will not include information for the A = 2, B = 2 case. Any thoughts on moving forward? This needs to be abstracted to large distinct values in both columns.

Comment: You would need to join your table to a table or derived table that contains every possible value combination of A & B, even if that combination doesn't exist in your main table.

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.A, a.B, count(*)
from
    (select distinct A from T) as a
    cross join
    (select distinct B from T) as b
    left outer join T as t on t.A = a.A and t.B = b.B
group by a.A, a.B
```

Comment: I think this will still only return rows that exist in T, since only columns from T are appearing in your select list.

Comment: Yeah, I got lost in my own aliasing scheme.